# RecyclerView hold first visible item while second item moving to first position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to hold first visible item while next item scrolling up in RecyclerView?

Comment: You could create a container above your RecyclerView that holds the view in a static position while the remainder of the list scrolls.

Comment: you want to sticky that first item while scrolling ?

Comment: I need hold first visible item and set opacity while next items scrolling up. And repeat it every time for first visible item.